# Where has my comment gone? And why?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477323/how-to-initialize-a-static-field-of-which-type-is-a-private-nested-class) user put some apparently valid code (modulo missing semicolons) with claim that he gets a compilation error. And then answered his own question with some solution.

I put his code in Ideone, fixing semicolons, checked that it compiles and put a link to it in a comment saying that code works for me. Also someone commented answer saying that it must be some problem with compiler, as the code is perfectly valid.

I looked at the question today and both comments are gone. Now the question is misleading as gives a "solution" to either different problem, that was posted ([here is the proof that code works](http://ideone.com/3BA2Bf)) or to a bug in a compiler. I could repost my comment but I guess it was removed for some reason. Any clue?

Comment: Guess: someone flagged your comments as obsolete after OP edited his question to include the missing `;`.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Actually, any comment will be deleted automatically if it gets enough flags (even if all the flags are from low rep users).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mat's guess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172452/where-has-my-comment-gone-and-why#comment511633_172452) is what happened here. Your comment was flagged as being obsolete, and I removed it as a result.

I noticed that the question had been edited since the comment was left, where they stated "Fixed a typo in the code: missing semi-colon." I had assumed that your comment was based on this older code with the typo, and was therefore no longer valid. That's why I removed it after it was flagged.

If that isn't the case, the proper course of action would be to re-post the comment. I see you've already done this, so there's not much more to do here.